# httpclient hard timout not working properly

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x

i am using CloseableHttpAsyncClient to perform number of requests without waiting for other to complete and i am setting up hard timout of 1 minute. But if suppose there are 10 requests then its taking 4-5 minutes to stop.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(3000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(3000)
            .setConnectTimeout(3000).build();
    CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
            .build();


TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (request != null) {
                        request.abort();
                        System.out.println( "request aborted");
                    }
                }
              };
            new Timer(true).schedule(task, hardTimeout * 10000);
```

Please tell me whats wrong in this.